# Oracle command, meaning of the part after sysdba

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Can someone please tell me what does it mean @test.sql in the Oracle command:

```
sqlplus sys/pw@somedb as sysdba @test.sql
```

Comment: Someone downvoted the question. OK, perhaps - but it is not entirely clear (not to me anyway) what was wrong with the question. So, to help dummies like myself, it would help to **explain** the downvote. (I am not holding my breath...)

Answer (score 3):

`test.sql` is a script to be executed.

This entire line logs into `somedb` with user `sys` using password `pw` as sysdba and runs the `test.sql` script.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer

Answer (score 0):

**sqlplus sys/pw@somedb as sysdba** can be also written as **sqlplus sys/pw@sid as sysdba** , it mean is you use passwordfile authorization and @test.sql is the script ,you want to get executed.